# How would I use Deja Dup on a password protected SMB share?

Tags: samba, deja-dup

How would I use Deja Dup to backup to a password protected SMB (on a samba server) share?

Note: not a duplicate, I put a bounty on my previous question, and nobody answered it after a month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is how it works for me:

1. In Deja Dup open Storage tab and choose Windows Share from drop-down list.
2. In Server enter ip address of your samba server.
3. In Folder enter path to path to directory where you want to store your backup.
4. In Username enter your samba username.
5. In Domain Name enter domain in which your samba server resides.

The only problem is that Deja Dup wants password every time it makes a backup. I guess solution is to mount samba share using fstab.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I use freenas (because it's awesome) and didn't set any domain name. Would the domain name be the NetBIOS name, the hostname, or what?

Comment: Try checking in freenas services: cifs:Workgroup.

Comment: Got it! Workgroup is local :S

Comment: What would the folder name be? The CIFS share name?

Comment: ^^ nevermind, it's the share name

Comment: I enter the server name instead of IP address (because it changes sometimes) and that works too.  I do not have to re-enter the password.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get Deja-Dup working with a remote Samba share; kept getting an invalid argument error when trying to connect.

For anyone interested though, I've found that the rsync tool works just as well for backups. To make rsync run a backup automatically, I just used the GUI for crontab ("Scheduled Tasks") to set the command to run once a week.

That's what I stumbled onto anyways, maybe someone else has a better way of doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Although this is interesting information, it is not really an answer to the question ;). You can however post it as a comment to the existing question.