# using deja dup to backup my ubuntu to a windows shared folder

Tags: windows, backup, deja-dup

I have a ubuntu 12.04 running and have certain things installed like samba,nagios and likewise-open to have my ubuntu join a windows domain. this all works correctly. I am not an expert in linux although I do know some basics.

What I am trying to do is use `deja-dup` to backup my ubuntu machine to a windows shared folder with the windows-share method?

at the server line I filled in the ip-address of my windows server.

at the folder I put `/smb://"mywindowsserver"/folder`

`username` is the username I created for backing up. (I have read somewhere that it usually works to have the same usernames on a Windows server and Ubuntu machine with backing up)

domain name my domain name.

I am not sure I have the syntax right at the folder it is supposed to back up to

When I click backup now it does connect to the windows server and it asks for a password. After I fill it in and press enter it says that it can't mount the windows share. When I go to that server with Ubuntu file explorer, it just connects and mounts the folder fine.

Has this something to do with permissions? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible dup of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/300733/how-would-i-use-deja-dup-on-a-password-protected-smb-share

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Following rbello1824's link I was able to resolve it. I had to select the custom location option and manually enter the location as:

```
smb://WORKGROUP\Username@server/Folder
```

Worked perfect! Thanks rbello!

Comment: That worked. Just as a hint, use `%20` for spaces in the share name.

Comment: Semicolon instead of the backslash seemed to be helpful for us although using the IP of the server was the real solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with entering the correct storage location on my Ubuntu 14.10. I had no success with *Backup location* set to *Windows Share*. After changing to *Custom* I tried using a URI in the form of:

```
smb://WORKGROUP\Username@server/Folder`
```

from the answer above, which didn't work either.  As I am using nemo as file manager I checked the URI to the shared folder, where I saw an URI in the form of

```
smb://domain;username@server/sharedfolder/folder
```

The difference is the semicolon between domain/workrgoup and username. This finally worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me, too! Interesting thing, on next time reopening the GUI, my config got converted back from "custom" to "Windows share". (which is not a problem, but rather kind of proof, that this format is accetable). Using latest Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue.  I found this somewhat old bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/1018488 that suggest issues with the smb path.  I've changed the URI in storage->backup location(custom location) to use the correct format.  I'm not sure if this is a fix but will test this evening when I'm able.

Answer (score 0):

I am running 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) I am able to connect to my windows share folder by using setting the Storage location as a Custom Location.  I set the URI to smb://WindowsServerName/$haredFolderName.  Once I set these two fields deja-dup worked correctly. The windows share I used was already set up on my computer.  Hope this helps,

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04.2(Elementary OS) I found that after installing deja dup, I was unable to backup to my onsite Linux server, this server running a vanilla samba version and a very vanilla smb.config file, so I actually used some knowledge I gained from having to mount an SMB file share in the dreaded Mac Terminal(for some reason it wouldn't mount in Finder) on a job site, and so after using a modified form of the URI on the "Custom Location" storage selection I was able to get it to work. Here is the modified code...

```
smb://WORKGROUP;sambausername@sambahostname/SMBShare
```

This worked for me and now my Linux laptop can be easily backed up, this was a much more painless process than having to have a Mac Backup up to an SMB Share...