# How to backup files from one ubuntu machine to a shared NTFS drive on another ubuntu machine

Tags: mount, samba, backup, ntfs, deja-dup

I'm dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop machine which has a large NTFS hard drive I'd like to use to backup files from 2 laptops. One runs only Ubuntu 12.04 and the other only Windows Vista.

I really only care about being able to backup my Ubuntu laptop to the NTFS drive on the desktop over the network. I guess the tricky part is that it's NTFS (can't get rid of Windows entirely yet).

I've been reading and reading and I'm close. I've installed samba, ntfs-config and ntfs-3g and I CAN access, read and write to the drive from my Ubuntu laptop.

This is why I can't understand why I get error messages like "Failed to mount Windows share" from programs like Deja Dup. I could easily copy my files to the NTFS drive directly but a proper backup tool obviously has major advantages...I just can't get any of them to work.

What samba settings are needed?
What ntfs-config settings are needed?
What deja dup settings are needed?
Isn't the drive already mounted if I'm able to access it from the laptop?

Comment: Hm, maybe this is more related to the access rights. Have you checked them? Reading/writing NTFS drives should be a great deal.

Comment: The samba server configuration is set to writable/visible and 'Allow access to everyone' and I'm allowed to access and edit the files from the laptop. I just can't get backup software to do it.

Comment: This works for Deja-dup. https://askubuntu.com/a/444351/286759 (check also the bug 1018488). So, use Other location in Dejadup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount your network share on the NTFS drive using `/etc/fstab` of your Ubuntu laptop. First of all you will need to install `cifs-utils` package. Create mountpoint in `/mnt` folder where the network share will be mapped, `/mnt/NTFS` for example. Then add the following line to your fstab file:

```
//IP_of_Network_Machine/Shared_folder /mnt/NTFS cifs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/Username/.sambapass,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

You also need to create `/home/Username/.sambapass` which will contain your network login and password to access the network share:

```
username=DOMAIN_or_WORKGROUP/Network_login
password=Network_password
```

Change keyfile's default permission to increase security and make it inaccessible by other users:

```
sudo chmod 600 /home/Username/.sambapass
```

On the next login your network share will be mounted automatically. Now this network share will exist in your filesystem as any local folder and can be easily accessed by any backup software.

Comment: No luck yet. I got cifs-utils on both machines, created the /mnt/NTFS dir on the laptop and entered the line in /etc/fstab with '192.168.11.6' (the inet address of the desktop) followed by the name of the folder shared via samba and my actual username. I also created .sambapass in my home dir with the username and password for the desktop.  But the situation is the same. I can access the drive via the 'Network' icon in the sidebar but it doesn't show up in /mnt/NTFS (should it?) When I do access it via 'Network' the address bar shows 'smb://desktophostname/sharedfoldername' Is that relevant?

Comment: If the remote folder was mounted properly it should show up in your /mnt/NTFS folder. Try mounting it manually with `sudo mount -t cifs -o iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/Username/.sambapass,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //IP_of_Network_Machine/Shared_folder /mnt/NTFS` and check your mountpoint and any errors in the process.

Comment: GOT IT! Thanks a ton @whtyger. I was just making the silly silly mistake of using my system password instead of my samba password in the .sambapass file. Once I entered the right password, the auto-mount and backup software are working great. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. I edited my answer to make it clear what password is needed. Also you can rename your keyfile and mount point as you see fit.